# Using operators in Database?

Tags: php, database, operators

[image]

^This is my database table with a variable in the 'firstCheck' a operator in the 'comparison' and the value in the 'secondCheck'.

```
//some code here where I fetch everything
if ($event0FirstCheck . $event0Operator . $event0SecondCheck) {
        $output .= $event0output;
    } else if ($event1FirstCheck . $event1Operator . $event1SecondCheck) {
        $output .= $event1output;
    } else {
        $output .= "something went wrong...";   
    }
```

If I echo the IF then this is the output: $gold>=100 
and if I echo the ELSE IF then this is the output: $gold<100

the good thing is that it can read the variable from the database but not the operator,

and my question is: is it possible to put operators in a database and when I fetch them use them as a operator?
please dont come up with 'you dont have to put operators in databases at all' 
I just want know if it is possible.

Comment: thanks Fabio for adding the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done yes, but not without your regular conditional statements but by creating your own class or function.

**example**

```
function condition($var1, $op, $var2) {

    switch ($op) {
        case "=":  return $var1 == $var2;
        case "!=": return $var1 != $var2;
        case ">=": return $var1 >= $var2;
        case "<=": return $var1 <= $var2;
        case ">":  return $var1 >  $var2;
        case "<":  return $var1 <  $var2;
    default:       return true;
    }   
}

if (condition($event0FirstCheck, $event0Operator, $event0SecondCheck)) {
    $output .= $event0FirstCheck.$event0Operator.$event0SecondCheck;
} else if (condition($event1FirstCheck, $event1Operator, $event1SecondCheck)) {
    $output .= $event1FirstCheck.$event1Operator.$event1SecondCheck;
} else {
    $output .= "something went wrong...";   
}
```

You can also use `eval()`, but this is a very dangerous method. If there happens to be any destructive php code in that database you are in big trouble ;)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

**eval() example**

```
$a1 = '$gold';
$b1 = 150;
$com1 = ">=";

$a2 = '$gold';
$b2 = 150;
$com2 = "<";

$gold = 100;

$str = 'if('.$a1.' '.$com1.' '.$b1.'){echo "'.$a1.' '.$com1.' '.$b1.'";}elseif('.$a2.' '.$com2.' '.$b2.'){echo "'.$a2.' '.$com2.' '.$b2.'";}else{echo "something is wrong...";}';
eval($str);
```